# Components a "bit" out of position with GridBagLayout - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm designing my first user interface completely from code by hand (with no use of any "drag and drop" IDE).

Therefore I've run into a problem with one form.
As you can see here in my layout screenshot:
[image: my form layout]

The textFields in red are not aligned with the From radio button. Same problem with the textfields in blue not aligned with the label "To:". They look like they are not aligned by one line but I'm using the same value for `gridy`, in the "From:" radio button and "To:" label.

The ones in green are slightly not aligned as well.

I've been all over my code but I can't find where's the mistake. Could someone help me out on aligning them properly?

**EDIT**

```
public void layoutComponents()
{
    //add to the layout (what is above )
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints(); //class that specifies where goes what we want



    ////////// Insert and Align Labels and Fields //////////


    gc.weightx = 1; // how much space it takes relatively to other cells
    gc.weighty = 1; // how much space it takes relatively to other cells
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    //specify to wich side it will stick to
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START; // stick to the right hand side

    Insets fivePixels = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);// adds 5 pixels of spcae to the right
    Insets zeroPixels = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0; //y increase downwards
    gc.insets = fivePixels;
    add(dataSourceBoldLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 1; //second row
    add(sourceTableLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 2;
    add(processDataPeriodLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 5;
    add(resultsBoldLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 6;
    add(writeResultsToNewTableRadio,gc);

    gc.gridy = 7;
    add(writeResultsToExistingTableRadio, gc);

    gc.gridy = 8;
    add(processDataOptionsLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 9;
    add(accessSessionTimeThresholdLabelLabel, gc);

    gc.gridy = 10;
    add(transitionTimeThresholdLabelLabel, gc);







    ///////////     Second Column  X = 1     ////////////


    gc.insets = zeroPixels;
    gc.gridx = 1;


    gc.gridy = 1;
    add(sourceTables, gc);

    gc.gridy = 2;
    add(allRadio, gc);

    gc.gridy = 3;
    add(fromRadio, gc);

    gc.gridy = 4;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    add(toLabel, gc);

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.gridy = 6;
    add(newTableField, gc);

    gc.gridy = 7;
    add(resultsTables, gc);

    gc.gridy = 9;
    add(accessSessionTimeThresholdField,gc);

    gc.gridy = 10;
    add(transitionTimeThresholdField, gc);

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST; //push the buttom to the top
    gc.gridy = 15;
    add(start, gc);



    ////////////////// Third Column    X = 2 //////////////////
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    add(fromDateField, gc);

    gc.gridy = 5;
    add(toDateField, gc);





    ///////////////// 4th Column    X = 3 /////////////////////
    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    add(fromTimeField, gc);

    gc.gridy = 5;
    add(toTimeField, gc);


}
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) For that GUI I would be tempted to use `GroupLayout` - but that was never intended to be hand coded..

Comment: I've edited my post to post a SSCCE.

Comment: There is almost 250 LOC in the 3rd class.  While I might still consider 250 lines to be 'short' enough for an SSCCE, many won't.  But that is beside the fact that it involves 3 x copy/paste of code to see it working.  An SSCCE is ***always one source file.***  Any code that is 2 or more source files is simply 'not an SSCCE'.  I suggest you a) Don't extend frame, just use an instance.  That puts the frame code in the `main()` and gets rid of one class.  Then.. b) Put the `main()` in the end of the source for the GBL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

It was on the gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.X where X is the direction. I was using different directions when I should keep it constant or match both columns and line with the correct direction.